# How do I use/not use headers tags in a footer so the code is WCAG 2.0 AA valid?

Tags: accessibility, wcag

Here is a sample of code that is not WCAG 2.0 AA valid. The part not valid is the use of H3 tag in the footer without a H2 being present between the H1 and H3 tags: *[WCAG v2 1.3.1 (A)] Nest headings properly (H1 > H2 > H3):*

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>test</h1>
    <p>lorem</p>
    <footer>
        <h3>test f</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
        </ul>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

considering the fact that the content before the footer is edited by an editor without proper knowledge about WCAG guidelines, what is the best way to code a WCAG website?

So far I see 2 solutions:

1. Not use h3 or any other header tags in the footer
2. Reset header nesting by adding a h1 and a h2 before the h3 in the footer and hide them from CSS.

I don't think any of these are good solutions. Here's why:
1. The footer is sometimes editable by a user(CMS use) and you have to always take into a account the content present before the footer content
2. I don't think hiding content with css is a good solution

Are there any solutions to this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [sectioning elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/content-models.html#sectioning-content-0): `section`, `article`, `nav` and `aside`.

Each sectioning element should get a heading. And you can always use `h1`!

So your example could look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>test</h1>
    <p>lorem</p>
    <footer>
      <section>
        <h1>test f</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
        </ul>
      </section>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you recommend doing if there are 3 or more columns in the footer. Will each column need a h1? This is hard to implement with custom content that is entered by users in a CMS(all headers need to be reset so they don't break the layout)

Comment: @orbitory: If each of these `footer` columns would have a "natural" heading (like "About this site", "Social", …), yes, use a `section` element for every column and use `h1` (or no heading at all).

Comment: @orbitory: When the CMS user should only enter "main content", simply include all his content (and the main content heading→`h1`) in `article` resp. `section`. So when all the user submitted content is inside of this sectioning element, no harm can be done to the overall page outline.

Comment: I suggest you read https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/page-structure/headings/ you should only have one h1 per page for accessibility reasons and semantics. It usually appears in the main body of the document rather than footer. If you had an h2 in the main section and an h1 in the footer it would confuse the screenreaders and probably be punished by Google.

Comment: @kahlan88: This WAI tutorial doesn’t seem to take sectioning elements into account. A sectioning content element’s heading can be of any rank (i.e, the rank doesn’t matter), because the outline algorithm calculates the correct rank. (But when having to support older user agents, it’s a good idea to use headings of the corresponding rank, where possible.)

Answer (score 0):

I do not recomend using too many h1. It is not against wcag, but different heading levels helps users of screen reader (such as me) understand the hierarchy. Skipping over heading levels is not the best either, but it is still better than having too many h1. I would suggest that use h3 always in the footer and if sometimes you are skipping from h1 to h3, then it is ok. users will understand it because that part is being repeated. it is not against wcag and it is much easier to understand for the actual users.